# Order of @PostConstruct and inheritance

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi

Let's suppose we have the following classes

```
public abstract class AbstractFoo {

    @PostConstruct
    private void doIt() {
       //
    }
}

public class Foo extends AbstractFoo {

    @PostConstruct
    private void doIt() {
       //
    }
}
```

When AbstractFoo.doIt() and Foo.doIt() will be called - what is the order?

Comment: What is stopping you from simply trying it?

Comment: @luk2302 I want to get canonical answer. I searched but couldn't find.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#fields_initializer_methods) is the *last* thing to get executed in the initialization of a given managed bean, relative to its position in the inheritance chain. From the spec

> The container must ensure that:
>
> - Initializer methods (i.e. `@PostConstruct`) declared by a class X in the type hierarchy of the bean are called after all injected fields declared by X or by superclasses of X have been initialized.
> - Any `@PostConstruct` callback declared by a class X in the type hierarchy of the bean is **called after all initializer methods declared by X or by superclasses of X have been called**, after all injected fields declared by X or by superclasses of X have been initialized.

**Pro Tip:** With CDI 2.0, [you can use `@Inject` to declare an initializer method](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#initializer_methods) as an alternative `@PostConstruct` and the restriction that you can have only one in a given class. The difference here is that `@PostConstruct` is *still* executed last and is the only place you can be guaranteed that all injected components will be available.

Comment: Initializer methods available in CDI 1.0 too!

Answer (score 4):

I did some tests and got a different behavior than what was expected after reading the 2 existing answers.

In your case, **ONLY** `Foo.doIt()` will be called via the `@PostConstruct`, but it is because of the overriding, not the annotation.

If you give different names to the methods of the parent and the child classes (so that there is no method overriding), then **BOTH** methods will be called via the `@PostConstruct` annotation, and the order will be : method from parent class first, and method from child class after.

(note: i was using Java 8 for this test, but maybe this could depend on the version ?)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `@PostConstruct` on the parent class is not called. There can be only one `@PostConstruct` method. So the methods of the parent class are not inspected. You need to explicitly call it by `super.doIt()`